# Count list items in data before outputting to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that is being returned using ajax that looks like this...

```
console.log(data);

<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>
```

I am inserting it into a HTML element like this...

```
$("#output").html(data);
```

This is working correctly, but I would like to count the number of list items before I output it to the element. I have tried the following but it just gives me the count of characters...

```
console.log(data.length);
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there a way to do this before outputting the HTML?

Comment: You have to convert the string into actual elements before you can count them.

Comment: Or do some sort of regexp finder to get all the `<li>` to count

Comment: @Taplar That's a terrible advice (especially because OP will add them to the DOM anyway)...

Comment: It's an option.  We can debate the worth of any option, but I'm not going to withhold any options I might think of.

Comment: I think converting to a jQuery object first is the way to go, but you _could_ count the occurrences of `<li>` like this `let data = "<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>";let count = (data.match(/<li>/g) || []).length;`.  I'd reiterate that you're much better off w/the jQuery object solution provided below though, which is why I upvoted it and did not submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is just a string, so you can use jQuery to turn it into jquery object and then select `li` elements from that object and get the length.

```js
const data = '<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>'
const html = $(data);

console.log(html.find('li').length)

$("#output").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Out of curiosity, does jQuery inject this HTML into a hidden part of the DOM in order to do element find/count operations on it? It would seem odd for it to do its own HTML parsing, when this is built into the browser.

Comment: @halfer Good question. The docs say `If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's .innerHTML mechanism` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument, but there is also `$.parseHTML` method https://jsfiddle.net/chguv9yb/, so I'm not sure.